# Using PI in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to access the value of pi in Python 2.7, but it seems as if Python doesn't recognize math.pi. I am using IDLE, and when I try to print the value of math.pi, it says that "Math is not defined" or "math is not defined". I can't upgrade to the next version without risk, so is there a way to access pi in Python 2.7? Alternatively, is there another way to convert degrees to radians in Python 2.7 without dealing with Pi?

Comment: Did you import the math module with `import math`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
```

Check out the [Python tutorial on modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and how to use them.

As for the second part of your question, Python comes with [batteries included](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#angular-conversion), of course:

```
>>> math.radians(90)
1.5707963267948966
>>> math.radians(180)
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 3):

To have access to stuff provided by `math` module, like `pi`. You need to import the module first:

```
import math
print (math.pi)
```